# Magento Connect Manager Downloader 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento

I have a Magento 1.7 clean install and I just finished uploading my products. I went to to go to System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager and I'm redirected to:

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/store2/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fxx.xx.xx.xxx%2Fstore2%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F

With a 500 Internal Server Error. I checked the Apache Error log and nothing is being posted about this. I also disabled the htaccess and that had no effect either. The permissions are set to the apache user (daemon) like all the rest of the files and I set the permissions to everything in Magento to 777. Not sure what else to do!!

Anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Rename(or delete) /downloader/**.htaccess** to **.htaccess.backup**