# Magento Connect Manager. HTTP error 500

Tags: magento

I have a running website on Magento 1.8 and unable to open Magento Connect Manager. Error HTTP 500 is displayed. I tried changing file permission of various file including index.php to 755 in public/downloader/ .
After using magento-cleanup tool my webiste home page is showed.
But still problem persist and unable to open magento connect manager.
Please provide solution.

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525273/magento-connect-manager-downloader-500-internal-server-error/41863167#41863167